# Deleting rows in MySQL tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, mailbox_conversation and mailbox_message.
Both tables have a common column, conversation_id.
The mailbox_conversation table has other columns named is_system and subject.

I would like to delete a specific conversation_id in the mailbox_message table if the following criteria are met:

- is_system =yes
- subject not like %Gift from%

Here is the code I have written:

```
$result42 = mysql_query("select * from ".TABLE_PREFIX."mailbox_message
         using ".TABLE_PREFIX."mailbox_conversation, ".TABLE_PREFIX."mailbox_message
          where ".TABLE_PREFIX."mailbox_conversation.conversation_id = ".TABLE_PREFIX."mailbox_message.conversation_id
        and ".TABLE_PREFIX."mailbox_conversation.subject NOT LIKE '%Gift from%'
         and ".TABLE_PREFIX."mailbox_conversation.is_system = 'yes' ");

$num42=mysql_numrows($result42);   **<<-- Line 73**
```

For testing purposes I did a select statement and want to output the number of rows  $num42

This is the error I receive:

```
Warning: mysql_numrows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in
/home/mayhem/public_html/videochat/admin/erasesysmess.php on line 73
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: Try printing the statement you're sending to the SQL server first, see if that shows what's wrong. `$toQuery = "select * from ".TABLE_PREFIX."mailbox_message using ".TABLE_PREFIX."mailbox_conversation, ".TABLE_PREFIX."mailbox_message where ".TABLE_PREFIX."mailbox_conversation.conversation_id = ".TABLE_PREFIX."mailbox_message.conversation_id and ".TABLE_PREFIX."mailbox_conversation.subject NOT LIKE '%Gift from%' and ".TABLE_PREFIX."mailbox_conversation.is_system = 'yes' ";

print($toQuery);`

Comment: What does the keyword `using` mean in that context? I've never seen this before.

Comment: @MarkByers: It's a syntactic short hand for the join condition when the column names are the same in both tables: `SELECT * FROM TableA JOIN TableB USING (Column1, Column2)` is equivalent to `SELECT * FROM TableA JOIN TableB ON TableA.Column1 = TableB.Column1 AND TableA.Column2 = TableB.Column2` OP has it specifiec in the wrong location, which is probably the source of his error.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli: Or maybe it's supposed to be [`DELETE ... USING ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)

Comment: Your query has failed, and you assumed success. At bare mininum you should have `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())` so that mysql can TELL you what's wrong.

Comment: Please do not use the deprecated `mysql_query` library in new applications. [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) or `mysqli` are significantly easier to use correctly and will be supported in newer versions of PHP.